# React app using Material UI hooks not showing styling in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

I have a react app using Material UI (v4). In my development environment it all works fine.
In production the styling does not seem to be applied.

I have read about class name generation being different in dev to prod and potential clashes but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I have a js file which looks like:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    someClass: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    },
});

export default useStyles;
```

I then have multiple tsx files which use this, something like:

```
const Example = (props: IExampleState) => {
    const styles = useStyles();

    return (
        <SomeMUIElement className={styles.someClass}>
            {some inner stuff}
        </SomeMUIElement>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: IExampleState) => {
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Calls);
```

In production none of these styling appear, and in dev tools I can see that there are no class names applied either, also appear to be no errors.

I'm sure I am missing something!